# Comparison SQL and SQLite DateTime EQUAL values results in False C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, datetime, uwp

I Create SQLite record with DateTime.UtcNow.

Then, I convert DateTime like this:

```
var format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fff";

var ModifiedString = _object.Modified.ToString(format);
var ModifiedFormatted = DateTime.ParseExact(ModifiedString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

This value is inserted into SQL along with other record's data:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Modified", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = ModifiedFormatted;
```

Then I query record and compare SQLite with SQL again to check whether DateTime value is the same(for testing it is the same). I get result that values are not equal:

I use Select * From TableName and:

```
_dbobject.Modified = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Modified"]);
```

Comparison is simply like this:

```
if (_object.Modified < _dbobject.Modified) 
{
    //update local
} else if (_object.Modified > _dbobject.Modified)
{
    //update online
} else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

The local or online records were not altered in the meantime but it always results as local being > than online.

Am I missing something?

Comment: *"Then I query record and compare SQLite with SQL again"* I assume if you say `"SQL"` i assume you mean `SQL Server` (MSSQL) and not MySQL?

Comment: Yes, I mistyped it

Comment: Also you should be using [DateTime.Compare()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=netframework-4.7.2) and not "simple" compare operators to compare datetime strings.. As it should be more safe.

Comment: Why are you converting `_object.Modified` in the first place?

Comment: oh, I dind't realize that. I will give it a try straight away

Comment: I was having problems with DateTime's between sqlite and sql previously. This is the workflow I am using and until now I didn;t have any problems.

Comment: @positiveperspective: I don't think that answers my question. Did you compare `ModifiedFormatted` to `_object.Modified` before you insert the record?

Comment: NO, I assumed that since I am converting _object.Modified to ModifiedFormatted I don't have to. It was due to SQL side DateTime problems that I came with this conversion before Insert to SQL.

Comment: should I use Formatted version of _object.Modified while comparing with SQL? As I say previously I did not notice any problems after implementing Formatted DateTime.

Comment: It is it being stored as a DateTime why are you converting? _dbobject.Modified = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Modified"]);

Comment: You should not compare any "formatted versions" but the actual `DateTime` objects.

Comment: formatted version is used to insert DateTime in correct format into SQL. without this I did not get right results. When I query SQL and compare DateTime again, I do not use formatter anymore as SQL already has correct format

Comment: Anyway, I am guessing it's due to the precision of milisecond between DateTime and DateTime2 where DateTime2 during conversion to DateTime Rounds up third position after second.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it was due to the millisecond precision between DateTime and DateTime2, where DateTime2 has more than 3 places after second and during conversion to DateTime it was rounding up/down resulting in values not being equal.

I trimmed two dates by:

```
DateTime date1 = _object.Modified.AddTicks(-_object.Modified.Ticks % TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);
```

and the same for the other date.

I don't result more precise than this so I am ok. However not everyone would be satisfied.